# Haskell - Parse error on input '='

Tags: haskell

```
getFloat :: IO Float

main = do
 putStr "Enter question number: "
 xs <- getLine
 if (xs == 3)
     then do
      main2
     else 
      main2

main2 = 
pricePizza ::  Double -> Double -> Double
pricePizza x y  = priceBase x  +  priceTopping x y * 1.6 

priceBase x = (3.14 * (x * 0.5) * x) * 0.001
priceTopping x y  = ((3.14 * (x * 0.5) * x) * 0.0002) * y
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: `main2 =` on its own is a problem… you have to implement `main2`.

Comment: @minitech sorry I should probably edit the question. there is going to be more funtions. so if xs = 3 then go to this function if xs = something else go to that function

Answer (score 3):

You can't have a line like:

```
 main2 =
```

on its own. It's a syntax error.

If you want to have keep some partially defined functions that you are still working on, you can use `undefined`:

```
main2 = undefined
```

or else put in some dummy code:

```
main2 =
```

Once that is fixed, you have two more problems:

1. You have a type for `getFloat`, but no definition. If you plan to define it later then you can give it an `undefined` value, otherwise you should remove it.
2. The type of `xs` is `String` so you can't compare it to `3`, which is and `Int`. You can just use a string literal instead.

I think this is what you were trying to do, and compiles:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
 putStr "Enter question number: "
 xs <- getLine
 if (xs == "3")
     then do
      main2
     else
      main2

main2 = putStrLn "main 2"

pricePizza ::  Double -> Double -> Double
pricePizza x y  = priceBase x  +  priceTopping x y * 1.6

priceBase x = (3.14 * (x * 0.5) * x) * 0.001
priceTopping x y  = ((3.14 * (x * 0.5) * x) * 0.0002) * y
```

Comment: this is exacthly what was needed apart from I need to define main2 to work with pricePizza now and im not too familiar with how to do that.

Comment: If you have some problems implementing that part, maybe ask a separate question.